# How do i get ubuntu 16.04.4 lts docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I see ubuntu 16.04 lts (not 16.04.4 lts) image in ubuntu repo in dockerhub. How do i get the latest ? or is the 16.04 lts is always updated with latest patch releases ?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

The image ubuntu:16.04 will contain the latest image, which will be 16.04.5.  To verify this, you can run the following:
`docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04` 
 `apt-get update` 
`apt-get install lsb-release` 
`lsb_release -a`
You should get the version of Ubuntu is running.